# Как ускорить выполнение программы, реализующей сортировку подсчетом?

Tags: c++

Лабораторная не выдерживает лимит по времени на последнем тесте (нужно менее 35 сек). Тесты закрыты.
Поправила то, что бросалось в глаза, все равно не проходит.
Как можно ускорить выполнение?

Задание:
Требуется разработать программу, осуществляющую ввод пар «ключ-значение», их упорядочивание по возрастанию ключа алгоритмом сортировки подсчетом за линейное время и вывод отсортированной последовательности.
Тип ключа: числа от 0 до 65535.
Тип значения: строки переменной длины (до 2048 символов).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 2050

//struct Pair consists of key(from 0 to 65535) and val(string with length 2048)
struct Pair
{
    unsigned short int key;
    char value[SIZE];
};

//struct Array to create an array of pairs
struct Array
{
    Pair* pair;
    int curSize;
    int capacity;
};

//печать массива
void print(Array* array)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < array->curSize)
    {
        std::cout << array->pair[i].key << "\t" << array->pair[i].value << "\n";
        ++i;
    }
}
//сортировка подсчетом
void CountingSort(Array* pairVector, unsigned short int max, Array* res) {
    unsigned int c[65536]; //вспомогательный массив
    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; i++)
        c[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pairVector->curSize; i++) {
        c[pairVector->pair[i].key] ++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 65536; i++)
    {
        c[i] += c[i - 1];
    }
    //с помощью этой операции мы сможем однозначно определить положение пары в результирующем массиве.
    //начинаем обход с конца, для того, чтобы оставить порядок значений одного ключа неизменным.
    //за счет предыдущего цикла сложность должна быть линейной.
    for (int i = pairVector->curSize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        c[pairVector->pair[i].key]--;
        //res->pair[c[pairVector->pair[i].key]] = pairVector->pair[i];
        res->pair[c[pairVector->pair[i].key]].key = pairVector->pair[i].key;
        strcpy(res->pair[c[pairVector->pair[i].key]].value, pairVector->pair[i].value);
    }
}



int main()
{
    unsigned short int key;
    unsigned short int max = 0;
    char value[SIZE];
    int size = 8;

    //выделение памяти под массив
    Array* pairVector = (Array*)malloc(sizeof(Array));
    pairVector->curSize = 0;
    pairVector->capacity = size;
    pairVector->pair = (Pair*)malloc(sizeof(Pair) * pairVector->capacity);

    //чтение исходного массива и нахождение максимального ключа
    while (std::cin >> key)
    {
        std::cin.getline(value, SIZE, '\n');
        if (pairVector->curSize == pairVector->capacity)
        {
            pairVector->capacity *= 2;
            pairVector->pair = (Pair*)realloc(pairVector->pair, sizeof(Pair) * pairVector->capacity);
        }

        pairVector->pair[pairVector->curSize].key = key;
        strcpy(pairVector->pair[pairVector->curSize].value, value);

        if (key > max)
            max = key;

        pairVector->curSize++;
    }
    //создание массива результатов
    Array* res = (Array*)malloc(sizeof(Array));
    res->curSize = pairVector->curSize;
    res->capacity = pairVector->capacity;
    res->pair = (Pair*)malloc(sizeof(Pair) * res->capacity);
    //выполнение сортировки, если членов массива больше, чем 1
    if (pairVector->curSize <= 1)
    {
        print(pairVector);
    }
    else
    {
        CountingSort(pairVector, max, res);
        print(res);
    }
    //system("pause");
    //чистка памяти
    free(pairVector->pair);
    free(pairVector);
    free(res->pair);
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вы не могли бы добавить в вопрос описание задачи? Так было бы проще разобраться в коде...

Comment: Если в `struct Pair` можно заменить `char value[SIZE];`  на `char *value;`, то можно сэкономить на realloc-ах в блоке чтения данных (каждый раз надо будет копировать меньше байт). Тогда надо делать `pairVector->pair[pairVector->curSize].value = strdup(value)` вместо `strcpy`

Comment: А задача реализовать сортировку именно подсчётом или вообще любой вид сортировки? А какой размер данных на которых не проходит по времени (за 35 сек)? Сколько элементов и какой максимальный размер каждого элемента (длина value)? Как то сомнительно что за 35 сек на современных компьютерах именно этот вид сортировки не сможет отсортировать гигабайты данных. У вас же всё равно не гигабайты данных? Думаю замедление (горловина) не в сортировке а в realloc при вводе данных.

Comment: Что-то не то, если вам 35 секунд не хватает... Давайте начнем сначала. 1. Прочтите хотя бы обзорную страницу сайта (о том, что вы этого не сделали, говорит отсутствие у вас медали "информированный"). 2. Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 3. Приведите точное и полное задание (не вашу его трактовку, а как оно задано). Например, ваша работа с `malloc` - это **указано в задании**? Почему именно так, а не С++? Какого примерно размера файл? Сомнения и в сортировке подсчетом - если бы были только ключи... но у вас же и значения. Может, изменить сам алгоритм?

Comment: Добавила описание задания. Нужна именно сортировка подсчетом, сортировка по ключам. Количество данных в тестах не указано, так что об объеме судить трудно.

Comment: Попробуйте в `CountingSort` число 65536 заменить на `max`. Предупреждение компилятора раздражает. Может как раз лишняя работа тормозит. Ещё также может ускорить поиск дополнительного **минимального** ключа, тогда когда все ключи большие будет бонус в скорости.

Comment: А как вы тестируете ваш код? У вас есть сервер на который вы шлёте код и он вам сообщает что мол тест 8-й не прошёл по времени? Или вам на руки файл с входными данными дают? Если сервер, то может он вам по вашему запросу может показать входные данные на которых не проходит код по времени? Интересно узнать сколько там элементов. Кстати бывают онлайн сервера которые сообщают что превышено время, когда программа крэшается (умирает по критической ошибке), т.е. просто программа вообще не отвечает и сервера ошибочно считают что время превышено. Может это ваш случай, т.е. у вас со скоростью всё ОК.

Comment: Ваш массив `c` размером 65536 занимает 256КБ-512КБ места в стэке, вполне может убить стэк переполнением. А это может быть причиной превышения времени, т.к. программа при подвисании/крэше тоже превышает время. Используйте malloc/free чтобы хранить массив счётчиков.

Answer (score 0):

Решил реализовать свою версию кода для вашей задачи (сортировки методом подсчёта), постарался в основном C++ концепции и классы использовать (отчего код может выглядеть относительно сложным).

Относительно вашего кода скажу вот что - выглядит по оптимизированности довольно неплохо, даже 65536 значений пробежать не проблема, миллисекунды. Подозреваю что причина превышения времени в тестах на самом деле другая - многие онлайн сервера, которым присылаешь код для тестирования, сообщают о превышении времени (Time Limit Exceeded) не только когда код исполнялся медленно, они часто это сообщают при любом случае когда код не выдал ответа за отведённое время. В частности когда был крэш (программа умерла изза критической ошибки, как доступ по нулевому указателю). Т.е. ваша программа могла умереть или подвиснуть изза критической ошибки и просто 35 секунд ничего не происходило, в итоге сервер ответил о превышении времени.

Ваш метод сортировки очень быстрый, один из самых быстрых возможных при определённом типе данных, поэтому 35 секунд для него достачно чтобы гигабайты отсортировать. Не думаю что в ваших тестах там гигабайты. Я уверен что реальная причина превышения времени в том что ваша программа или крэшнулась (умерла) или подвисла изза критической ошибки (например разыменование битого указателя). Т.е. вам нужно как раз ошибки в коде искать, а не ускорять код, код итак довольно оптимизированный. При этом такой быстрой сортировке даже оптимизации не особо помогут, она итак будет миллисекунды работать.

Основные источники критических ошибок в Си-подобном С++ коде это - работа с сырыми указателями, неинициализированные указатели и обычные переменные, разыменование указателей содержащих нули или мусор, неверные точки вызова malloc/free, переполнение стэка. У ваc массив размером 65536 элементов вполне может переполнить стэк, он занимает от 256КБ до 512КБ (в зависимости от размера int), это очень много для стэка, попробуйте его создавать не в стэке а через malloc/free. Также было бы идеально чтобы вы использовали классы и функции стандартной С++ библиотеки, такие как std::vector и std::string, вместо malloc/free ручного и работы с char-массивами строк.

Вот [исправленный ваш код](https://tio.run/##jVfrThtXEP6/TzEiP7KLLxgSRygGSxFCVf7QCppWKkFou17DqmbX3V0ncSNLhIjSCAqvYsAu5mL3Fc4@EZ055@zVS2VL4MPMnLl8czsY7XbJaOn23uPjs4bZtGwTdtc2f9zdWl97t7m@u/H97s9vNjfebny3pSjPLNtodRomrFiO57umflBP0JBi2XvlfaRJRVtvf1mHpUq1oigLC8juGD78oFsuGI7tWZ7vgdOE38yu2nSdA6iA78CravVFVQPdbsAHvaUKnfDR8vehZdp7@LVUebmsKQltymcF8NNBlXu22QBv33F9sGyfVNc4z9jXXdLXMbfJp52a0qslfHrjunqXrBsYk2@iddA5Cd1rowVPSQpKe2R6nrOFDTJodNwt6w8zQdDbumH53dAg@5cNgxPWD46CM2APePgSfGEjdsX6ygfHakAb4/VVbmdeOKFJe6TOglWoCO0f962WCaoFK0KsVJfGNc4Wd@jj@Y3Xrw2n48NKJEpeb1s7ZQSIqHPv/bkcLgdM8O25WqSwULDEHz2lhyGh/5PgMDhio@CQTTCSO9YHjHPCBhjcCcZ7hOcHEd6a07F9zOgWpiiMksz9ZBq@4xbzknigfyqCFHVNT4NMuklmHgxERk3TtAO91XIMlUrqFYp4CI7TTAlpWg0wKVcYAzn8gD/XlBw2ZPfBGRsHp@w2lSZuuum4CHyUDqAccCN4LBS0CCgDQYwTlncrDj1Kn9CRyJ@xnZRKZG4HMxEmYsrAYr5bn9POFVbpG0qwuJPUREmFEJHgW3AWnEPwN88jwjHhRXyIoPyJkIwQn@AUEB5C7x9E7oFEBmyMv2/wdx9rAM/8Ht4aIgvRxWrhLUBG7uXFMaobEqmP9XQK7Aq4/E3wlbIhKiz4GpwH34SVZPsMy9JzaXFE36Ezl8ExuQQU1R2exuh5vwjoyX1wATyuazYpQnDCz5dkfIKqj1DFVcJTNH@BlybsDqLQhNu3cczXFOsdaj6nRgekDVHgBr0lUSqph8jXGxQImwRCeFBigGFSkKSLo4z6uKjEaizcI7cGHEAioS30XFDvOQBDdstdui1PF0hO6VEdUNnURX2WStM181QplkrxfFhYwDaV7Kdv7GR8kLxYzUxK@ATLVVSOhr8Ygq7R7qqz6eRzr5irlLO0VNe5pqkaSOop@BEDy7JVbYatlD/s4okxvbXCPUCjDOWWcafISrqiquGNlewjbM0L6hs5j6dH2dQIpjEqiOH4lGOTEzUZel7xRG6nmHL/IdeLFmMWWLLJt2nGJNE0mM9VqEWh86aNgh5heMfpXkxtWSAwqHOPeSMN4psoxu64GJ34@J/q5uTmFXvVsqFep5Tmr13LLu@ZfgsfQ6qsKspkEZ6/t59rcXlaTVBzMV3NDz66GNt7Evn5VViqPSmWxh@fPzwBWYkizJaS0EJPUZ4ytp0TZ9jGeS07230JbtieKWBJd506S0uhIFqNm8x1VupO71jx3MG5PcAaiQsnUV@ZldXnGyXVbDiEZusyPq3i9sp7LCTk4k7LS05CcpaWS6mU7sgpIzb2OGqcnPffCHfrkC@rEe5UOZOQNdWLl6QLcfqLDWn78n29qPxfR6zg0ybbauLNHEun5rPZ8syMfOoRmnx98qcmvTFrGd0xLSwDr@v55oE619Y7njkXIUQvD/5wkI/gaALHuyJb0PJuhpekRlnLEKMy8TuuTdO3pzw@vgD9V0NZrEDDVKrQ/h3/eVmGT13lPw) в котором вместо стэкового массива счётчиков размером 65536 использован malloc/free вариант массива. Попробуйте, запросто может заработает этот вариант на вашем тестирующем сервере без превышения времени.

Мой код довольно обобщённый, может сортировать любой контейнер из пар (ключ, значение) любого типа, не только 16-битный ключ и строковое значение, но любой целочисленный тип ключа и любой тип значения.

Из ускорений сделанных в моём коде это вычисление min/max значений для ограничения массива счётчиков, также для экономии ОЗУ. Также использован [std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) для быстрого перемещения строковых значений вместо копирования. Всюду использованы классы и функции стандартной С++ библиотеки. У меня нет работы с сырыми указателями или плэйн массивами, также нет сишного выделения памяти (malloc/free).

Проверено на небольших тестовых данных, мой код выводит верный ответ.

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##jVRLj9owEL7nV0y3UpUIsiKqtqrYbC5VTz12b1uEvI4Bi8RJnQkLrfjtdOw4YNOttjmAPY9vvnmZt23KK6bWp9N7qXjVlwLyneDY6CK6SLBvK@ELeIelVOiLOtRSrX2JbEgmWO3LKllL7ALsQyuWqNmVmFXrRkvc1GGMUuy5aClwhKJuK4YOQbFawJdG4WMR7RpZ0rlXSIS@Nxpjq4APUDJkCfyOgL6@Iy18E4dHeAACns9LwdlhiTn9VwYzttK1wHxWxMb1abZIkuLeulvHWqrd6K36WmjJl0OGudEX83nN9nEytR72o/tbHlLFyRBj1WiIWY8N8EZ1SAmIeZCDRfQ4GF9zn4JPXSQO75qAIWfu/zA/2l@rGkYi7@Qv6lUBXGFnPSEd4k8ge5PzmcJkYvyfwpgOaeGhDNFAEt3snv5yG/fWiKlCBCMvmBZRLmDy4I6ElzmwoftadLaJzt@n26Iu5WrlYp1vgbnBMySKB5jdQ5p6sQn5KU3/yslOjFycM1ucy97sxFk70DC3QE2YpDpGEW0Z9czMhOs56oPX/aA75mxXNe/JLfu0RNdZt5uFjXOZhZeNrATEqHvhT5TdDgcAW3EAk3KgtaBcKiBIMgiVcgXxu9EiCVTme6YnYfsK3MARdqx6RUklraRyG0mwU2OXhIa2W/ZR4GL5zPg2dkO@pSkyVYmJ6tSrsYHwV@N4PgWPhx3ei9V/DPilRE2PkOdX62UkNz/wJtBko8ZKhCq9MmiBvVZjE47AGfLNkN3wHMpGXdjsk@v5GGncfB2t52Cji/3ty4Zh/EbgNBsfhGN0On0E9syjbAaliO6g/am76DPsD9Ef)

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename ContT>
void CountingSort(ContT & data) {
    using KeyT = std::decay_t<decltype(std::get<0>(data[0]))>;
    KeyT minv = std::numeric_limits<KeyT>::max(),
         maxv = std::numeric_limits<KeyT>::min();
    for (auto const & e: data) {
        minv = std::min(minv, std::get<0>(e));
        maxv = std::max(maxv, std::get<0>(e));
    }
    std::vector<size_t> cnts(maxv - minv + 1);
    for (auto const & e: data)
        ++cnts[std::get<0>(e) - minv];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < cnts.size(); ++i)
        cnts[i] += cnts[i - 1];
    ContT res(data.size());
    for (ptrdiff_t i = ptrdiff_t(data.size()) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        res[--cnts[std::get<0>(data[i]) - minv]] = std::move(data[i]);
    data = std::move(res);
}

int main() {
    try {
        std::vector<std::tuple<uint16_t, std::string>> data;
        while (true) {
            uint16_t key = 0;
            std::cin >> key;
            if (!std::cin)
                break;
            std::string val;
            std::getline(std::cin, val);
            data.emplace_back(std::make_tuple(key, std::move(val)));
        }
        CountingSort(data);
        for (auto const & e: data)
            std::cout << std::get<0>(e) << "\t" << std::get<1>(e) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    } catch(std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Ввод:

```
3 abc
10 de
5 pqrs
8 xy
```

Вывод:

```
3        abc
5        pqrs
8        xy
10       de
```